# Using Boost::filesystem in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost

I need to iterate through files in a folder using C++ and I am using Boost filesystem library for that purpose.

I am trying to run the tutorial code in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/filesystem/doc/tutorial.html

After installing boost, running bootstrap.sh to build all libraries followed by ./b2, I am able to run some simple code. But when I try to compile the following code from the tutorial

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        std::cout << "Usage: a.out path\n";
        return 1;
    }
    path my_path(argv[1]);
    std::cout << argv[1] << " " << file_size(my_path) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

using

```
g++ f1.cpp -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system
```

I get the following error:-

```
/tmp/cc3IJurw.o: In function `boost::filesystem::file_size(boost::filesystem::path const&)':
f1.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost10filesystem9file_sizeERKNS0_4pathE[boost::filesystem::file_size(boost::filesystem::path const&)]+0x19): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::file_size(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
/tmp/cc3IJurw.o: In function `boost::filesystem::path::path<char*>(char* const&, boost::enable_if<boost::filesystem::path_traits::is_pathable<boost::decay<char*>::type>, void>::type*)':
f1.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost10filesystem4pathC2IPcEERKT_PNS_9enable_ifINS0_11path_traits11is_pathableINS_5decayIS4_E4typeEEEvE4typeE[_ZN5boost10filesystem4pathC5IPcEERKT_PNS_9enable_ifINS0_11path_traits11is_pathableINS_5decayIS4_E4typeEEEvE4typeE]+0x22): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::codecvt()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Does anyone know a fix to this?

Comment: Linker error, you're not including the correct libs in the g++ command line.  I don't know what the correct command line is off of the top of my head (else this would be an answer), but that's your problem.

Comment: Well, maybe not, it looks like you installed boost from source, rather than using the package manager?  If so, I would urge you to uninstall the source and install `libboost` using `apt-get`, because installing it from source might have put headers and binaries where it's not being expected.

Comment: You can let gcc know where to "expect" them. so, no need to uninstall...

Comment: Abe Lincoln says you have built a 32-bit flavor of boost on a 64-bit system.